# How to request the desktop version of a webpage in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, user-agent

I've tried to request the desktop version of a webpage in this way but it doesn't work and I can't find anything on the web to help me

```
let url = NSURL(string: "*****")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

let newUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.6 Safari/537.11"

request.setValue(newUserAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User_Agent")

webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: It's `User-Agent`, not `User_Agent`.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227332/how-can-i-request-a-desktop-version-of-a-webpage-using-uiwebview-in-swift-3-0/38228810#38228810)