# How can I request a desktop version of a webpage using UIWebView in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, swift3

[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWu5H.png)
Actually I tried to find it from other sources, but there is nowhere clear answer that will be working perfectly. (example : [How to request the desktop version of a webpage in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816464/how-to-request-the-desktop-version-of-a-webpage-in-swift-2))

Please, help up. Provide the answer with the workable example.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason that you're using UIWebView, I would consider switching to WKWebView which is more up to date and newer as well as having the customUserAgent property.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Could You provide the sample code for WKWebView desktop request?

Comment: Just posted an answer that will hopefully fix your problem. Let me know if there are any further issues :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A WKWebView should solve your problem - you can define it in your code. Do this:

```
var webView : WKWebView!
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
    self.webView!.uiDelegate = self
    webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
    //load URL here
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)


}
```

Comment: Well, I'm very new to Swift, and my line is looks like this, but then I should add loadRequest lines right?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Sorry for the confusion. That's what I meant with //load URL here

Comment: uff. I don't know how to properly insert the code here)))

Comment: @Dmytro I edited my answer to include loading the URL for Apple's homepage. After you confirm it works, you can change the URL to whatever you like. Hope this helps :)

Comment: But should I assign that web view to the @IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!

?

Comment: @Dmytro No. WKWebViews cannot be created in the storyboard so no outlets are necessary. What I posted should be the complete answer. If you copy and paste it into your swift file it should work. Is something not working?

Comment: The webView is created in the code in my answer on the var webView line and then subsequently in viewDidAppear the size of the webView is set. Everything should work exactly as is - no other setup should be required including nothing in the storyboard.

Comment: I getting a lot of Swift compiler errors What am I doing wrong? Can I send You the Screenshot?

Comment: Sure - you can put the screenshot in your original question. You can also email it to me at tibor@phonefiveme.com if you prefer.

Comment: Sorry For a delay. I have attached the link in the beginning for the screenshot

Comment: @Dmytro I updated my answer. Try it now by replacing the old code with the updated code in my answer. Sorry about that :)

Comment: There error has gone, but the screen in the emulator is blank the I launching the app with the code

Comment: At the top of your class it says class className: UIViewController. At , WKUIDelegate after the uiviewcontroller

Comment: Then in viewdidload do self.webView.uiDelegate = self

Comment: @Dmytro try doing self.webView!.uiDelegate = self and self.view.addSubview(webView)

Comment: again fatal error in the line of
self.webView!.uiDelegate = self

Comment: Try the new code in my answer - make sure to re-copy and paste the whole thing. Delete the delegate line in your viewdidload that you already have because it's now included in the code

Comment: last thing is that last line in Xcode 8 give a mistakes:
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

Comment: and fix it like this : webView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))

Comment: but after, there is a still white blank view

Comment: Are you connected to the internet on the device you're testing it on?

Comment: try doing self.view.frame instead of self.view.bounds.  Or try self.view = self.webView

Comment: Try self.view = self.webView. Also make sure you give it time to load especially if your connection is bad

Comment: webView = WKWebView(frame: self.webView.frame, configuration: config)

Comment: self.view.frame not self.webView.frame

Comment: You can try getting a different URL or getting rid of the custom user agent string line and see if it works but at this point it's the WKWebView not the desktop part that's causing you problems

Comment: I have removed line
webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A"

Comment: just insert Your line of the code in the SingleView Template for iOS in Xcode 8

Comment: change the url to the one in my answer and you'll see it present a desktop website

Comment: @Dmytro try copying and pasting it now

Comment: @Dmytro If it worked, would you mind upvoting my answer and marking it as the correct one. Thanks - glad I could help :)

Comment: I'm checking it now

Comment: Yeeees! That is working. Thank You so much for Your kind effort. Really You did a good job. Sure, I'll mark Yours as a solution

Answer (score 2):

This works great! :)

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.samplepage.com")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

webview.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"

webView.load(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 version**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.samplepage.com")

let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "Custom-Agent"])

webView.loadRequest(request)
```