# Swift iOS how to get desktop version URL response

Tags: ios, swift, url, desktop

I want to get the desktop version URL response in iOS devices. But I always get the mobile version URL response. Here is my code:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")!)
request.addValue("Chrome Safari", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
let session = URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

That code will get mobile version response. How can I get desktop version URL response?

I want to get the `og` information of the desktop response, not using `WKWebView` to present website.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:

[How can I request a desktop version of a webpage using UIWebView in Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227332/how-can-i-request-a-desktop-version-of-a-webpage-using-uiwebview-in-swift-3-0)

Answer:

You could use WKWebView `customUserAgent` property to get a desktop version of web-page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414950-customuseragent

`webview.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"`

Of course, you need to modify the web-browsers version to get an actual response:

Mozilla Firefox:
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/

Google Chrome:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/chrome

Apple Safari:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/safari